# Getting the ip address automatically on localhost using trust proxy

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, ip-address

I have enabled `trust proxy` option to get the ip adress of the remote client. When the application is deployed on a remote server then I get the right address from `req.ip` but when the application runs on localhost then I get this address `::ffff:10.0.2.2`. Does it exist a way to make thing work both in localhost and in the remote?